# Toilet won’t flush and found this floating in the cistern

Tags: toilet, cistern

Toilet won’t flush when using the handle. It’s like there is air in the mechanism which doesn’t allow it to fill. Found this floating in the cistern.

[image]

The whole cistern fills up fully but when you pull the handle it feels like there is air in the reservoir and only allows a little bit of water out. After a few attempts it flushes.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe include a picture of the inside on the cistern and valve.

Comment: A little more clarity on the situation too please; is the cistern not filling up at all or not fully? Does anything at all happen when using the handle?

Comment: The whole cistern fills up fully but when you pull the handle it feels like there is air in the reservoir and only allows a little bit of water out after a few attempts it flushes

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer that helped you the most, or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer.

Answer (score 1):

Flush mechanisms are fairly straightforward. Diagnosing the problem is the first step. Correcting the problem may require an adjustment or a new flush mechanism.

**Diagnosis**

- With the lid off of the cistern push down on the flush handle. The lever inside should be connected to the flap (usually with a chain) that releases the water at the bottom of the cistern. From the picture it appears that the connecting chain may be loose or disconnecred.
- The mystery part floating in your cistern is probably part of that connection.
- Try pulling up the flap by hand and let it release. If it flushes normally the solution is in restoring the lever to flap connection. You might be able to do that by reconnecting everything or simply replace the flush mechanism which you should be able to buy at any Home Center for a few dollars.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that your siphon is similar to the one I've just replaced. We were having trouble flushing it, so I just swapped it out. The one I removed had two holes spaced about 1 1/2" apart on the side, which were obviously letting air in.
I bet that if you look on the side of the main siphon body you will find a couple of holes which this rubber piece should close.

They must be designed to allow you a coarse way of setting flush volume.

God only knows what happened to ours, I suppose it must've got sucked up and flushed, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a rubber link , usually a S link to rubber to chain , flip the Handel and look for a chain not connected to anything , usually a flapper valve in the bottom of the tank...
Don’t worry that water is as clean as the water you drink out of the faucet if you put your arm in the bottom of the tank and pull the flapper up it will flush if the tank is full.